# Set Max Upload File Size for SFTP connections

Tags: sftp

Suppose if I want to limit each upload to be at 25 MB via SFTP, how can I make this possible? Do I add a line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config for that? I tried to look for this information via Google search but I couldn't find it at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think many sftpd packages support this by default, but I admit that I have not done exhaustive research. My recommendation would be to go beyond sftp and limit the max file size for a user on the system more generally.

See:
http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf

`username     hard     fsize     25000` Should be close to what you want. But I cannot guarantee the SFTP error message will be pretty.

---

The other thing to keep in mind is that if your sftp package is part of your ssh package, SFTP users usually have SSH access when they have sftp access. `cat 'someLargeGBFile.zip' | ssh myUsername@yourhost.com cat > MyNewFileOnYourServer.zip` May bypass any restrictions that are ONLY placed on the SFTP daemon.

Comment: You are right, I was perplexed by this too. I couldn't find anywhere that SFTP can support this at all. Therefore, I asked the client what he exactly mean by his request. He actually meant that he would like to have Wordpress to limit the upload file size to 25 MB. After a short research, I could easily configure php.ini and nginx.conf to set this limit.